# How to prevent a child from exceeding its parent width in flexbox?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I need two flex items in a flex container.

One item to the left that has a fixed size and another on the right that fills the remaining space without exceeding the width of the window.

I tried to do this on a [**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/alerusso/u9heaw02/1/) and I have this problem: When I try to put some items inside a flex container inside the right item, it exceeds the width of the parent.

How can I prevent this?

**html**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="side"></div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
            <div class="large"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**scss**

```
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  height:100%;
}
.container {
display: flex;
  height: 100%;

  .side{
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width:3em;
    background: yellow;
  }

  .right{
    display:flex;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    background: blue;
  }
}

.large{
  width:120px;
  height:1em;
  background: green;
}

.flex{
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `flex` div?

Comment: Remove this line: `flex: 1 0 auto;`

Comment: @Paulie_D because i have it on my project. I need it because it a component.

Comment: @TechWisdom if i remove this line nothing appen.

Comment: @Ale_info, are you sure? Did you remove it from the `.right` class? Change it and hit "Run" once again in your Fiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, you have this:

```
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: blue;
}
```

The `flex` shorthand breaks down to:

```
flex-grow: 1
flex-shrink: 0
flex-basis: auto
```

Since you have `flex-shrink: 0`, the flex item (which is also a flex container), is not able to shrink.

You also have `flex-basis` set to `auto`, allowing the item to expand based on content-size.

Put them both together and you have a flex container with no reason to wrap and overflowing content.

You need to either (1) enable `flex-shrink` or (2) switch to `flex-basis: 0`.

Make this adjustment to your code:

```
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* fs: 1 (formerly 0) */
  background: blue;
}
```

OR

```
.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1; /* fg: 1, fs: 1, fb: 0 */
  background: blue;
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

.side {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  width: 3em;
  background: yellow;
}

.right {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto; /* adjustment */
  background: blue;
}

.large {
  width: 120px;
  height: 1em;
  background: green;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="side"></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="flex">
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
      <div class="large"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have a snippet here of what you're looking for. The red container has a display: flex, the blue element on the left has a fixed width, and the green container takes up the remaining width. The inside-right elements are contained within the green element, each taking up the same amount of space.

```css
.container {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
}
.container .left {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}
.container .right {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
}
.container .right .inside-right {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">

  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="inside-right">
    
    </div>
        <div class="inside-right">
    
    </div>
        <div class="inside-right">
    
    </div>
        <div class="inside-right">
    
    </div>
        <div class="inside-right">
    
    </div>
        <div class="inside-right">
    
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Many thanks, your answer is perfect! But if i put width instead of flex on inside-right class the container go on overflow. How i can resolve this?

Comment: it will always eventually overflow, because the parent has a fixed with. are you saying you'd like for all the parents of inside-right to adjust their width based on the combined width of the inside-right elements?